# vertical scroll bar disappears when DIV is in overflow state ( I.E. only)

Tags: html, css

I have the following DIV in I.E. (version 9 and 8) :

```
<div stlye="width:820px;height:350px;overflow:auto"> some large text blah blah .... </div>
```

both horizontal and vertical scroll bars display right on all browsers except IE, it only displays the horizontal one, and then, I have to scroll vertically using the mouse.

is there a solution for this problem ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed this snippet with every browsers (including IE 7, 8 and 9) and I have no problems.
Your style attribute is misspelled but I guess it's a typo...

Optionally, you can try this instead of "overflow:auto;" :

```css
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
```

But this is the normal behaviour of "overflow:auto;".

Comment: oops, i forgot to mention the DIV was within a span element, that's why it didn't work ... anyway, thank you for your answer.